# How to apply formula to WHOLE column and automatically add this formula to new created rows in this column?

Tags: google-sheets

I need some kind of "autoincrement field" in my spreadsheet. I've added `=ROW()` formula to first column. But as I'm adding new rows - I have to apply this formula to new created rows as well. Is there any ways to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following formula for that:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A))`

I strongly advise you to use hard coded Id's. If for some reason the sheet gets re-arranged, then the Id's will follow with that re-arrangement. An `ARRAYFORMULA` will stick to its plan and present the range as ever.